# How can I make an object detect another object that it has collided with is a certain leyer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a Ladder for my game but when I try to see if the collided object is in the layer "Ladder" it won't work. without these if statements they work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ladder : MonoBehaviour

{

    public Transform chController;
    public bool inside = false;
    public float speedUpDown = 3.2f;
    private ConciseMovement FPSInput;
    public LayerMask layerMask = 8;

    void Start()
    {
        FPSInput = GetComponent<ConciseMovement>();
        inside = false;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == layerMask)
        {
            inside = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == layerMask)
        {
            inside = false;
        }

    }


    void Update()
    {

        if (inside && Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            chController.transform.position += Vector3.up / speedUpDown;
        }

        if (inside && Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            chController.transform.position += Vector3.down / speedUpDown;
        }


        if (inside)
        {
            Debug.Log("is Ladder");
            GetComponent<ConciseMovement>().enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Not Ladder");

        }
    }
}
```

For myself, I made it so the script looks for another script called "climbable" instead of using layermasks. I will keep this post up for people who need to use layermasks and have their own problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layer and LayerMask are different.

From unity [Layers and Layer Masks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/layers-and-layermasks.html):

> A layer is a standard integer, but a layerMask is an integer formatted as a bitmask.

You can check if the layer is set in the layermask using

```
layermask == (layermask | (1 << layer))
```

Solution from a unity discussion found [here](https://discussions.unity.com/t/check-if-layer-is-in-layermask/16007)

To implement in your script, you can make a function that returns a bool, and use that as your condition.

```
private bool IsLayerInLayerMask(int layer, LayerMask layerMask)
{
    return layerMask == (layerMask | (1 << layer));
}
```

Then in your trigger functions use this function, like below.

```
if (IsLayerInLayerMask(other.gameObject.layer, layerMask))
{
    Debug.Log($"Layer is in LayerMask!");
}
```

Comment: Im not quite sure how I should implement this

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: Should it look like this

Comment: 'public int layerMask = 8;

    private bool IsLayerInLayerMask(int layer, LayerMask layerMask)
    {
        return layerMask == (layerMask | (1 << layer));
    }

 void Start()
 {
  FPSInput = GetComponent<ConciseMovement>();
  inside = false;
 }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (IsLayerInLayerMask(other.gameObject.layer, layerMask))
        {
            inside = true;
            
        }
    }'

Comment: yeah that looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could rather configure the [Physics Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsManager.html) -> [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) to only ever detect collisions between certain layers in the first place! (For instance between e.g. "Player" and "Ladder")

[image]

---

As another alternative I once made [this attribute](https://gist.github.com/der-hugo/1b8e7e6af69b6a87183b178305c10cc8)

> ```
> public class SingleLayerAttribute : PropertyAttribute
> {
> #if UNITY_EDITOR
>     [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SingleLayerAttribute))]
>     public class SingleLayerAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
>     {
>         public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
>         {
>             using (new EditorGUI.PropertyScope(position, label, property))
>             {
>                 position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, label);
>
>                 if (property.propertyType != SerializedPropertyType.Integer)
>                 {
>                     EditorGUI.HelpBox(position, $"{nameof(SingleLayerAttribute)} can only be used on fields of type int!", MessageType.Error);
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     property.intValue = EditorGUI.LayerField(position, property.intValue);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> #endif
> }
> ```

which you can use like e.g.

```
[SingleLayer]
public int layerMask;
```

This is basically the equivalent to the LayerMask dropdown but this time will allow you to only select a single layer and then properly works with `==` comparison.